# StackEditからBloggerに投稿したら画像とコードの部分がはみ出る

Tags: css, markdown

始めて質問します。
いろいろ調べたことを残すためにブログを始めてみようと思い、StackEditからBloggerに投稿が可能ということで始めてみました。

いざStackEditからtemplateを使って投稿してみましたが、以下のように画像部分とCodeの部分が本文のエリアからはみ出してしまいました。

[image: 画像]

cssの変更が必要かと思い、css自身をstackeditのgithubからDLし、google driveに置いて読み込むまではできました。min-widthの設定とかもいじってみたのですが、改善しません。

どうしたら画像部分、code部分が本文のエリアに収まるかを教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: テンプレートの問題だと思われます。どのテンプレートを使用したかで原因は変わってくるので、どのようなテンプレートを使用したか、できれば、 CSS の記述はどうなっているかも書くようにしてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiroshi Yamamotoさんアドバイスありがとございます。
使っているテンプレートはBloggerの一般的なもので、
CSSは、https://stackedit.io/res-min/themes/base.cssです。

もう少し調べた結果、以下に近い内容がありました。
　　参考：[StackEditを使ってMarkdown記法の投稿を書いてみた](http://island00.blogspot.jp/2014/02/stackeditmarkdown_1057.html)

ただ2回投稿するのは面倒なので、もう少し解析したところ投稿時にcustom templateとし、
以下のように修正することで解決しました。

[修正前]

```
<body><div class="container"><%= documentHTML %></div></body>
```

[修正後]

```
<body><%= documentHTML %></body>
```